# Problème de configuration Appium pour iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I have a problem to communicate between my macmini and my iphone 7 (version 11.4) with Appium. My build is successfull on xCode and the version of Appium is the last 1.18.0-1.
My capabilities in Appium are :

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "11.4",
  "bundleId": "com.altran.deltadore.tydom",
  "deviceName": "iPhone7",
  "udid": "0afc3d4352c3f2d720a9ffca2d971b118b9a7e17",
  "xcodeSigningId": "jerome.thomoux@altran.com",
  "xcodeOrgId": "WUQ4U559T2",
  "automation_name": "XCUITest"
}
```

The error message in Appium when I start the session is :
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: App with bundle identifier 'com.altran.deltadore.tydom' unknown

Comment: Please write the title in English too.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more capability as :

```
"app" : "Path_to_your_ipa_file";
```

Secondly, you have to add udid while signing the ipa build for the devices you have to use the build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it as soon as possible